# Why in the above code it skips input string for n=1

Tags: java

When I run the above code,
it skips the first input string and without taking the input string, it prints hs.size() and jumps to n=2.But from n=2, the code runs absolutely fine.It takes the input string and adds in the hash set.

**Why it skips the input string for n=1??**
Please help.

```
public class ch 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HashSet hs=new HashSet();
        String s;
        Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=console.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   
            s=console.nextLine();
            hs.add(s);
            System.out.println(hs.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Save yourself some confusion and try to almost always use `nextLine` and do the `parseInt` after

Answer (score 0):

It is because nextLine() directly after nextXXX() (XXX being any of Int, Float Double,etc) creates problem.
nextXXX do not parse \n and nextLine() in such a case reads only \n left behind by nextXXX().
To resolve the issue, you can use an extra nextLine() just below nextInt() and your code will work just fine..